# How do I find edge points on an arc given radius, sweep and start angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to draw an arc with rounded edges in one of my project, but i'm having hard time figuring out `Math` to draw the rounded edged on an arc.

this is what I have so far

```
val size = Size(500, 250)
val xOrigin = size.width / 2f
val height = size.height
val stroke = 60
val outerRadius = size.width / 2f
val innerRadius = outerRadius - stroke
val startAngle = -180f
val sweep = 45f
val center = Offset(xOrigin, height)
```

based on above information i was able to figure out I was able to draw two rectangles and to achieve the arc below. My question is how do I find x,y points of the edges (one circled in black) or x,y points of the corners start point (the one in second arc with rounded red corner). So that I can draw a path from those two points to make an arc?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image]

// rectangle 1

```
Rect(
  left = center.x - outerRadius,
  top = center.y - outerRadius,
  right = center.x + outerRadius,
  bottom = center.y + outerRadius,
),
startAngle ,
sweep
```

// rectangle 2

```
Rect(
  left = center.x - innerRadius,
  top = center.y - innerRadius,
  right = center.x + innerRadius,
  bottom = center.y + innerRadius,
),
startAngle + sweep ,
- sweep
```

I drew both of this rect using `Path` and `acrTo` function provided by canvas library in Jetpack compose to achieve the red arc in the image.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you please edit it again? Where are the two rectangles?

Comment: updated the question with rectangle measurements and angles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the 'curved rectangle' is defined by two circles centered at the origin with radii: (inner) $r_1$ , and (outer) $r_2$, and the angle at which the rectangle is cut is $\theta$, as measured from the positive $x$ axis.

Let the radius of the circle to be cut out be $r$, then all you need is to find the center of this circle.  Consider the corner of the 'curved rectangle' close to the inner circle which of radius $r_1$.  Let $A$ be the point

$ A = (r_1 + u ) (\cos \theta, \sin \theta ) $

From $A$ go to point $B$ (The center of the cut-out circular arc) given by

$ B = ( (r_1 + u) \cos \theta - r \sin \theta, (r_1 + u) \sin \theta + r \cos \theta ) $

Now you want the distance between $B$ and the origin to be $ r_1 + r $.

Thus

$(r_1 + r)^2 = (r_1 + u)^2 + r^2$

Simplifying

$2 r_1 r = 2 r_1 u + u^2$

And this is a quadratic equation in $u$ which can be solved by quadratic formula.  Namely,

$ u = \left(\dfrac{1}{2} \right) ( - 2 r_1 + \sqrt{ 4 r_1^2 + 8 r_1 r } ) $

Simplifying the above expression, we get

$ u =   - r_1 + \sqrt{ r_1^2 + 2 r_1 r }  $

Having found $u$, the center of the cut-out circular arc (point $B$) is now known.

Point $A$ is the start of the arc, and point $C$ is the end of the arc, where

$C = \dfrac{ r_1 }{ r_1 + r } B $

For the corner at $r_2$, point $A$ is

$ A = (r_2 - u ) (\cos \theta, \sin \theta ) $

And point $B$ is

$ B = ( (r_2 - u) \cos \theta - r \sin \theta, (r_2 - u) \sin \theta + r \cos \theta ) $

Therefore, the equation determining $u$ becomes

And the solution is

$ u =   r_2 - \sqrt{  r_2^2 - 2 r r_2 }$

with this, point $B$ (the center ) is detemined, and point $C$ (the end point on the outer circle is given by

$ C = \dfrac{r_2}{r_2 - r} B $

The above is valid if chamfering counter clockwise from the straight edge.  If chamfering the other end (clockwise), then point $A$ is the same, but $B$ becomes

$ B = ( (r_1 + u) \cos \theta + r \sin \theta, (r_1 + u) \sin \theta - r \cos \theta ) $

for $r_1$ corner , and

$ B = ( (r_2 - u) \cos \theta + r \sin \theta, (r_2 - u) \sin \theta - r \cos \theta ) $

for $r_2$ corner.

$C$ formulas are the same.

For example, take the 'curved rectangle' with inner radius $5 cm$ and outer radius $10 cm$, and let $\theta = 60^\circ $ and $r = 1 cm$

The below figure shows the application of the above formulas. The curved rectangle is shown in black while the cut-out circular arc is shown in red.

[image]

[image]
[image]